# On Banach-Schauder theorem (open-mapping)

Tags: operator-theory, open-map

**Theorem** Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T \in {\cal B}(X,Y)$ a surjective linear map. Then $T$ is an *open map* (that is, it sends open sets in open sets and the inverse $T^{-1}$ is continuous).

---

Now, in order $T^{-1}$ to exists in the first place, it's necessary that $T$ is injective. Is every surjective open map also injective?

Secondly, if this is really enough to guarantee the continuity of $T^{-1}$, and hence its boundedness, then what's the difference between this theorem and the so-called *bounded inverse theorem*?

Comment: I don't agree with your claim that $T^{-1}$ must be continuous. An open map simply sends open sets to open sets. If the map is injective, this is equivalent to its image being open and its inverse being continuous in the subspace topology of the image, but without injectivity this criterion is just to be ignored.

Comment: Take $Y$ to be the scalar field to see why $T$ need not be injective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $T \in {\cal B}(X,Y)$ is surjective, then, in general, $T$ is not injective.

Example: $X=Y=l^2$ and $T(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_2,x_3,...).$

If $T \in {\cal B}(X,Y)$ is bijective, then $T^{-1}$ is bounded. That is the bounded inverse theorem.

Comment: Why the downvote ??????????????????????????????